# Help with JPQL query

Tags: jpa, jpql, openjpa

I have to query a `Message` that is in a provided list of `Groups` and has not been `Deactivated` by the current user. Here is some pseudo code to illustrate the properties and entities:

```
class Message {
  private int messageId; 
  private String messageText;
}

class Group {
  private String groupId;
  private int messageId;
}

class Deactivated {
  private String userId;
  private int messageId;
}
```

Here is an idea of what I need to query for, it's the last AND clause that I don't know how to do (I made up the compound `NOT IN` expression). Filtering the deactivated messages by userId can result in multiple messageIds, how can I check if that subset of rows does not contain the messageId?

```
SELECT msg FROM Message msg, Group group, Deactivated unactive
WHERE 
  group.messageId = msg.messageId 
  AND (group.groupId = 'groupA' OR group.groupId = 'groupB' OR ...) 
  AND ('someUserId', msg.messageId) NOT IN (unactive.userId, unactive.messageId)
```

Note: The `...` is there because I don't know the number of groupIds ahead of time. I receive them as a `Collection<String>` so I'll need to traverse them and add them to the JPQL dynamically.

Comment: Could you clarify the problem (btw, you could use `AND group.groupId IN (:list)` instead of multiple `OR`)?

Comment: Thanks for the tip to reduce the branch conditions. The problem is `('someUserId', msg.messageId) NOT IN (unactive.userId, unactive.messageId)` is invalid - I don't know how to construct this part of the query. Perhaps a subquery is in order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are making a cartesian product in your query. You need to have a subquery to reach to your result. you can have a query like this :

```
 SELECT msg
 FROM Message msg, Group grp
 WHERE msg.id = grp.msgId 
       AND grp.id IN (...)
       AND msg.id NOT IN (SELECT msgId FROM Desactivated WHERE userId = 'uid')
```